# How to interpret "operator const char*()" in operator overloading?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was looking at one of the implementation of String class and noticed the following overloaded == operator.

```
String f = "something";
String g = "somethingelse";
if (f == g)
    cout << "Strings are equal." << endl;

bool operator==(String sString)
{
    return strcmp(operator const char*(), (const char*)sString) == 0; 
}
```

I understood most of the part except `operator const char*()` what exactly its been used for?
I have very basic knowledge of operator overloading , can someone please throw some more light on this?

Comment: I think `operator const char*()` is an explicitly called `(const char *)` operator on 'this' pointer.

Comment: Do you mean CString, String (what is that? CLI stuff?) or std::string?

Comment: Its some custom `String` implementation in c++, other than the default implementation of `string` class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an explicit call to the `operator const char*()` member function. This code would do the same:

```
return strcmp(static_cast<const char*>(*this), (const char*)sString) == 0;
```

But there are more than one thing wrong with that code:

1. it should not use C-cast, but C++-casts (e.g. `static_cast`) for the right argument
2. `operator==` should be a free function, not a member function
3. A string class should normally not have an `operator const char*`
4. If the `String` class is implemented reasonably, the `operator==` should take both parameters as const references

Comment: +1 For anyone that wonders about the warrant for #3, [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096210/why-does-stdstring-not-provide-a-conversion-to-const-char)

Comment: Also, using two different means of achieving the same thing.  Whatever means chosen for the first argument (and explicitly calling `operator char const*()` is probably the least intuitive and idiomatic) should be used for the second argument as well.  (As to whether `static_cast` or a C style cast, this is largely a question of style.  In this case, anyway.)

Comment: @James of course it is a question of style. As is the choice of explicit operator calling ;)

Comment: All styles are equal.  But some are more equal than others:-).  I've never seen code which used the explicit call of a conversion operator; in fact, the explicit call of an operator in general seems limited to forwarding functions (e.g. the postfix `operator++( int )` might call `operator++()`.)  There are also conventions where there is a strong underlying technical argument: casts between pointer types should always use C++ casts, for example.  On the other hand, _most_ programmers I've seen prefer `(double)someInt` to `static_cast<double>( someInt )`.

Comment: What's wrong with `operator==` being a member function besides lack of commutative property?

Comment: @icepack that way the first argument *has* to be a `String` and can't be anything convertible into a `String`. e.g. `String foo; if("something" == foo)` would not compile. If `op==` is a free function, the first parameter can be converted like any normal function parameter.

Comment: @ArneMertz That's exactly what the lack of commutativity means. I prefer to implement whatever possible as member and complete the missing functionality by external free implementation (which will be very simple here - just call the member operator with operands order reversed). That's more aligned with OO principles, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

`operator const char*()` is the old-style C casting: just like you can cast an integer to float by (float)int_var, you can cast to `const char*` as `(const char*)string_var`. Here it cast a String to `const char *`

If you're familiar with the STL `std::string`, then this `operator const char*()` is doing basically the same job as `.c_str()` there.

Answer (score 1):

This is an explicit call to the cast-to-`const char*` operator which is overloaded by your `String` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This operator will cast it's own `String` to `const char*` and call strcmp.