# Overload operator const char* for retrofitting in-place?

Tags: c++, string, class, implicit-conversion

I'm working with a bunch of existing tests like the following (there are literally a couple of hundred of them):

```
bool Test_X(const char* file) {
    ...
}
```

And it would be called like:

```
result = Test_X("TestData/test-set-X.bin");
```

The problem is after `make install`, the `TestData` is no longer in `$PWD` so the test program fails with a `file not found` error.

I want to create a `Locate` class that tries to abstract away the differences. To make it minimally invasive, I want to use it like:

```
result = Test_X(Locate("TestData/test-set-X.bin"));
```

To make that work, I think need to overload `operator const char*` (and some friends). However, that runs afoul with the rule:

- Automatic casts are almost always evil

See, for example, this question/answer on Stack Overflow: [Why does std::string not provide a conversion to const char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4096210).

The problem gets a little more complex because the tests need to work when faced with `make PREFIX=/usr/local && sudo make install PREFIX=/usr/local`. So I need to propagate the [make directory variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Variables.html) down into the C++ code.

Is the overload my only option and therefore a necessary evil in this case? Or are there other solutions I am missing?

Comment: `Test_X(Locate("blah").c_str())`?

Comment: Why should `Locate` ever be a class?

Comment: @n.m. - I I think for two reasons. First, its a C++ library and the author of the library is going to want a certain degree of OOP (he does not use preprocessor macros for string concatenation). Second, I need to do some processing based on the path provided to `Locate`. Its either going to be `$(prefix)/share/<lib name>/TestData` or `./`. Packaging data and their functions begs for a C++ class.

Comment: @jww  Why Function object does not meet needs?

Comment: "Packaging data and their functions". You are doing it wrong. You are fetching the prefix from some **static** data which is not a part of `Locate`. Static data is not "packaged with a class" in any real sense. If you were doing something like `Locator loc(prefix); ....; loc.locate(path);` that would be packaging data (`prefix`) together with a function (`locate`). What you have is a plain old standalone function that you are shoehorning into a class for reasons unknown.

Comment: @n.m. - please forgive my ignorance.... Why would I not use a static variable since its constant across all instances of the class? And how is a common value shared across all instances of a class somehow invalidating OOP? *"... you are shoehorning into a class for reasons unknown"* - OK, so I told you why. You seem to disagree, which ***is not*** an unknown reason. Perhaps you should share the code you would use.

Comment: You can use static variables, but a static variable doesn't justify existence of a class. If all you have in your class is a static piece of data and one function, you don't have a legitimate class in the OOP sense. You may just as well use a standalone function. You may use a C++ class construct like a namespace, but it's not a real class and it has nothing to do with OOP. You have OOP when you have a virtual function. No VF, no OOP. On top of that, instead of using a honest little *named* function like `Locator::locate()` you are using a cast operator, which makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: To reiterate, you can have OOP and static data together, but you have no OOP if **all** you have is a piece of static data. The C++ keyword "class" doesn't magically make your program object-oriented.

Comment: *"You may just as well use a standalone function."* - I'd like to, but I can't return the `char*` where its needed. So I believe I need a class. Perhaps you should share the code you would use. I'm very interested in how you would design your solution. *"instead of using a honest little named function like Locator::locate()..."* - again, I don't believe I can. You really should share the code you would use.

Comment: *"You have OOP when you have a virtual function"* - Its been a few years since I had it in college, but I don't believe this is correct. Encapsulation has always been an OOP concept. Where are you getting your definition of OOP? You really should share the code you would use.

Comment: The cast operator behaves exactly the same as any other function. Thus, `Locator("...").locate()` will do the job. The better solution is to never use `char*`, ever. Use `std::string` throughout.

Comment: Encapsulation exists in other programming paradigms too, it is not a defining characteristic of OOP (though an important one).

Comment: I would use a standalone function like `std::string locate_file(const std::string& in_path) {...}`.

Comment: I would disagree with some experts. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I do not quite understand your question. So I could only try to answer this question, I hope this can help you.

**Function Object OK?**

```
class Locate{
public:
    Locate(const string& pwd):pwd(pwd){}
    const char* operator()(const char* suffix){
            string result=pwd+suffix;
            return result.c_str();
    }
private:
    string pwd;  
};
```

use sample:

```
Locate locate("yourpwd");
Test_X(locate("TestData/test-set-X.bin")); #not Locate,it is locate
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. What don't you understand about the question?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: @jww  Why Function object and c_str does not meet needs? Thanks

Comment: I don't really know what a function object would like like in this context. If its the code you shared above, then I already have that. I'd like to know if its correct, or if there's a better way to do it. Also, because its in-place, you won't be able to declare variables of that type (i.e., `Locate locate(...)`). Its going to be a bunch of anonymous temporaries.

Comment: @jww - OK,I believe you encounter a lot of challenges, I will continue to focus on this issue, thank you